# How to open link in the new window using autohotkey?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

I have tried the following code :

```
        n::^LButton
```

but it didn't work.

Answer (score -1):

Its shift click to open in new window (at least in firefox). So you'd use a `+` not a `^`.

Comment: Just realized how old this question is.